# I cannot connect to oracle database from client pc

Tags: oracle10g, windows-server-2012, vmware-workstation

### I cannot connect to oracle database from client pc

**PC#1:** let's call it server. already have static IP and the OS is windows server 2012

 **PC#2:** let's call it client.

**in server PC,**
I tried to ping client pc result: ok 
also, I tried to connect to oracle database from sqlplus result: connected
additionally tried by oracle developer result: connected fine.
I did configure a listener and then in firewall added port 1521. 
I also used 
 - lsnrctl status 
 - lsnrctl stop 
 - lsnrctl start

**I also tried to change manually on tnsnames.ora and Listener.ora**

**in client pc.**
I tried to ping server pc result: ok.
but when I tried to connect to oracle database from sqlplus result: failure and error shown: ora-12170. 
 
also, I tried by oracle developer result: couldn't connect

I literally tried everything I could think of... please help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be old but maybe someone is having the same problem

I did solve this by turning off the firewall on the server-side and client-side
also if you have antivirus make sure to turn it off

Answer (score 0):

If database server is up and running (as well as the database) and you can establish connection to the database from the server, and if PC and server are in the same network, it *should* work.

One option is to create/edit client TNSNAMES.ORA file and put database's alias into it.

Another is to use easy connect string; on client PC you'd then

```
sqlplus username/password@db_server_ip_address:port/service_name
```

or - using live example

```
sqlplus scott/tiger@15.14.13.12:1521/orcl
```

What happens when you try it?

Comment: When I try this method sqlplus scott/tiger@15.14.13.12:1521/orcl
and the other one same error 
The ERROR as following:

ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred